# Objective C: Memory Leak issue in Class Method

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am hitting the memory leak warning message as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

I need some advise on how I can resolve this memory leak. Can I just do a [self release] at the end of the method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not assigning the object returned to `_sharedUserStockInfo` so you are losing reference and leaking. Over that `_sharedUserStockInfo` will remain `nil` and method will return `nil` too.

Comment: @Zhen, Exactly what was said. " *You are not assigning the object returned to _sharedUserStockInfo* " so go ahead and assign `[[self alloc] init]` to `_sharedUserStockInfo`.

Comment: @sidyll, thanks for your response. After i do that, is it necessary to release _shareUserStockInfo at the end of the method?

Comment: @Zhen Like sidyll already has commented, you can replace `[[self alloc] init];` with `_sharedUserStockInfo = [[self alloc] init];`. You don't need to `release` it at the end of the method.

Answer (score 3):

```
+(UserStockInfo*)shareduserStockInfo{

     @synchronized([UserStockInfo class])
     {

         if(! _sharedUserStockInfo)
             _sharedUserStockInfo= [[self alloc]init];
         return _sharedUserStockInfo; 
     }

     return nil;
}
```